# Função de logout usando PHP PDO Orientado a objetos

Tags: php, pdo

Estou com um grande problema com a função de deslogar do painel, fiz uma *public function Logout()*

Arquivo *Login.class.php:*

```
public function Logout(){
    if($this->isLogged()) {
        unset($_SESSION[$this->prefix.['email']]);
        unset($_SESSION[$this->prefix.['password']]);
        session_destroy();

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

E no meu arquivo *panel.php* está assim:

```
session_start();
$Logins = new Logins();
if (!$Logins->isLogged()) {
    header("Location: ?pag=login");
} else {}
if(isset($_GET['action']) == 'logout') {
    if($Logins->Logout()) {
        header("Location: ?pag=login");
    }
}
```

Agora que estou tendo problemas, estou a exatamente 8 horas empacado nisso, quando clico em Logout ele volta para home.php mas a *session* não destrói, não acontece absolutamente nada. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Deve haver um erro de sintaxe em `unset($_SESSION[$this->prefix.['email']])` e `unset($_SESSION[$this->prefix.['password']])`, devido aos `.` depois de *prefix*.

Comment: Opa eu concertei, porém nada foi resolvido ainda, ficou assim agora `unset($_SESSION[$this->prefix.'email']); unset($_SESSION[$this->prefix.'password']);`

Comment: Deixei como você disse e ainda nada... :'(

Comment: O que é `prefix`? se essas informações estão numa *session* tente acessa-la assim: `unset($_SESSION['email']);` e `unset($_SESSION['password']);`

Comment: `prefix` é um *parâmetro* de configuração que eu fiz, pra mim mudar o nome da `session` a hora que eu achar necessário entendeu? Sim já tentei também deste jeito porém nada ainda acho que devo estar fazendo algo de errado e bem feio ainda rsrs. :'(

Comment: vish. Como você guarda o *e-mail* e a *senha* na *session*?

Comment: Bom, meu código está muito extenso então vou coloca-lo no **Pastebin** http://pastebin.com/hNbbQdFE

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23831/discussion-between-guilherme-alves-and-qmechanik).

Comment: Pequena sugestão: `$_SESSION[$this->name]['email']` não seria melhor que usar o prefix?